# Display a list field in a custom form with QGIS and Qt Designer

Tags: qgis-3, qt-designer

I'm building a form with `Qt Designer` and I want to show attributes of my table when I interrogate an object. I design this form with a `.ui` file.

With integers and strings fields I'm using `QLineEdit` and don't have any issues. But I can't display attributes with a list field, `QGIS` crash.

I've tried `QListView`, `QTableView`, `QListWidget` and `QTableWidget`, same result.

How can I display a list field? Which class of `QObject` I have to use?

I'm using `QGIS 3.10 (LTR)` and `Qt Designer 5.11.2`

**EDIT**

Here are my form settings. A the level of "creation" field (list) I want to see my multiples values, like in a drop-down menu where the user can scroll.

[image: Form]
[image: QDialog]

Here are my `QGIS` settings. As you can see, "creation" field is a list.

[image: QGIS]

[image: field]

How can I display this kind of list? (form generate automatically)

[image: list]

Comment: in order to help you better, can you attach your code and screenshots of the desired result?

Comment: I've edited my post to provide details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example, I have created a layer with one field "creation".

Firstly, in Qt Designer, you must add a QComboBox widget. With a QComboBox, the user can only choose one value. Each widget have an object name. The QComboBox must have the same name as the field you want to fill in in QGIS.

[image: qt_designer]

Secondly, in QGIS :

1. You load your .ui file
2. You choose your field
3. You choose your widget type (value map for your example)
4. Fill in the table with the list of your desired values (you can add values directly in Qt Designer but it doesn't work within the framework of the attribute forms.

[image: attributes_form]

In your QGIS project :

1. Edit your layer
2. Add a feature
3. Choose the value

[image: qgis_project]

Is that what you wanted or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I understand the link beetwen Qt Designer and QGIS. In your example, you put a combox box with predefine data but how can i have a table with multiple elements ? (from my list) Not a predefine list, just a list with possibility for the user to add or remove some values.I edit my original post with a screenshot to be more explicit.

Comment: The user can add or remove some values from the attribute form, do you think it's too complicated for the user or unsuitable? Do you want the user to be able to choose several values for each feature?

Comment: For each feature, the user must have possibility to add or remove several values in the "creation" field, because it's a list. Automatically generated form display a multiple item menu, I want to reproduce this manually with Qt Designer widgets.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible in the forms because you add 2 buttons "+" and "-" on which you have to program signals and slots.

Comment: Indeed. I'm surprised that there is no Qt widgets for this.